# Visual Studio 2013 hangs when build a Android Project

Tags: java, visual-studio-2013, xamarin.android

I'm trying Xamarin and made a few projects to play around and it's being a good experience so far, almost flawless. Now and then when I start to build a project, always Android, Visual Studio hangs. What I noticed, if I kill java.exe VS back to normal and then I able to rebuild again. Any thoughts on that?
My setup is Windows 10 Pro and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 5. Also I'm using Microsoft Android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, I found out Xamarin instead build the app was downloading m2repository in a zip file. The size varies from 60MB up 250MB in my particular case. Once file was downloaded the build happens flawlessly.
If delete these files, Xamarin will download it again.

The folder is C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips